# Add multiple column value corresponding to a specific column value in new column in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-science

I have a Pyspark data-frame like below:

```
+---------+--------+-------+------+--------------+-------------+----------+
|     NID |    Time|N1     |Gender|P1            |M1           |Occupation| and so on...
+---------+--------+-------+------+--------------+-------------+----------+
|     1   | 10 AM  |  10   |     M|     100      |    50       | Teacher  |              
|     2   | 2  PM  |  20   |     M|     200      |    50       |  Doctor  |                  
+---------+--------+-------+------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

let's say if NID is 2 then how to add corresponding value from different column like:

```
if NID ==2 then N1(20) + P1(200) + M1(50)
result = absolute value (270) =270
```

**can we make it generic so it can be applied on n number of columns.**

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What should happend if `NID != 2`?

Comment: please give more examples

Comment: @kfkhalili i have to calculate for each nid value eg. - for NID = 1 result will be 160 i.e addition of Corresponding of NID column (N1 is 10, P1 is 100 and M1 is 50)

Comment: @Steven I am applying logic like ` import pyspark.sql.functions as F     
df.filter(col("NID") == 1).agg((F.sum("N1")) + (F.sum("P1") ) + (F.sum("M1") )).collect()[0][0 ]`   but this is not taking column randomly and this is not generic for all column

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark: Use When , Otherwise Condition for this issue. example  : `df.withColumn("result", when(col("NID") == 2 , col("N1") + col("P1") + col("M1"))).show().`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are probably several ways to do this.

```py
# Let's set up the problem.
data = [(1, "10 AM", 10, "M", 100, 50, "Teacher"), (2, "2 PM", 20, "M", 200, 50, "Doctor")]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
cols = ["NID", "Time", "N1", "Gender", "P1", "M1", "Occupation"]
df = rdd.toDF(cols)

df.show()
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+
#|NID| Time| N1|Gender| P1| M1|Occupation|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+
#|  1|10 AM| 10|     M|100| 50|   Teacher|
#|  2| 2 PM| 20|     M|200| 50|    Doctor|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+
```

So, you could export the logic of deciding what to do based on `NID` to a function and then use that function to generate a new column with the correct value for every record.

```py
# You could make this function take all the columns and use only what's needed
def f_based_on_nid(nid, n1, p1, m1):
  switcher = {
    1: n1 + p1 + m1,
    2: n1 + p1,
    3: n1
  }
  return switcher.get(nid, 0) # returns 0 if an unknown NID is given

# Then you make it a User Defined Function (UDF)
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
f_based_on_nid_udf = \
  udf(lambda nid, n1, p1, m1: f_based_on_nids(nid, n1, p1, m1), IntegerType())


# Which then you use to generate a new column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
new_df = df.withColumn("calc_based_on_nid", \
  f_based_on_nid_udf(col("nid"), col("n1"), col("p1"), col("m1")))


new_df.show()
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
#|NID| Time| N1|Gender| P1| M1|Occupation|calc_based_on_nid|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
#|  1|10 AM| 10|     M|100| 50|   Teacher|              160|
#|  2| 2 PM| 20|     M|200| 50|    Doctor|              220|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
```

So that's one way. Another would be to make your base function take a variable-length `*args`. The function then creates a tuple of the arguments which you have to parse to work with, but I don't think you can get away from having to pass all the required columns. I like the first approach, because it is far more readable.

Here is the second way anyway.

```py
# Same approach but assuming that number of arguments given is correct.
# This is bad in my opinion.
def varargs_f_based_on_nid(*args):
  nid, *rest = args
  switcher = {
    1: rest[0] + rest[1] + rest[2],
    2: rest[0] + rest[1],
    3: rest[0]
  }
  return switcher.get(nid, 0)

# Then you do the same with a UDF
varargs_f_based_on_nid_udf = \
  udf(lambda *args: varargs_f_based_on_nid(*args), IntegerType())

# Applying it in the same way
new_df = df.withColumn("calc_based_on_nid", \
  varargs_f_based_on_nid_udf(col("nid"), col("n1"), col("p1"), col("m1")))

# Same result, just less readable
new_df.show()
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
#|NID| Time| N1|Gender| P1| M1|Occupation|calc_based_on_nid|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
#|  1|10 AM| 10|     M|100| 50|   Teacher|              160|
#|  2| 2 PM| 20|     M|200| 50|    Doctor|              220|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
```

Another alternative is to export the logic into the `withColumn` call itself

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
# chain calls to when, finishing with an otherwise
new_df = df.withColumn("calc_based_on_nid", \
  when(col("NID") == 1, col("N1") + col("P1") + col("M1")).\
  when(col("NID") == 2, col("N1") + col("P1")).\
  when(col("NID") == 3, col("N1")).\
  otherwise(0))

# Same result, no UDF was used
new_df.show()
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
#|NID| Time| N1|Gender| P1| M1|Occupation|calc_based_on_nid|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
#|  1|10 AM| 10|     M|100| 50|   Teacher|              160|
#|  2| 2 PM| 20|     M|200| 50|    Doctor|              220|
#+---+-----+---+------+---+---+----------+-----------------+
```

So there are multiple approaches, but either your function signature defines the number of arguments to receive, or your function definition deals with a preset number of arguments, or the `when` function deals with specific cases and their respective arguments, so the number of arguments is always predetermined before the function is called.